# Sphinx real time indexes config?

Tags: php, sphinx

i am new to Sphinx i need sample code for real time indexex sphinx.config in linux sever?

Comment: as you are new to sphinx you should start reading here http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/

Comment: i am already read sphinx.and implement normal indexes but how to implement reaL time indexes?give one example?sorry fro the late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For near real time indexing you can use delta method :

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/delta-updates.html

**Edit:**

Index everything :

```
indexer --rotate --config /home/myuser/sphinx.conf --all
```

Index only delta :

```
indexer --rotate --config /home/myuser/sphinx.conf delta
```

Merge indexes :

```
indexer --merge main delta --rotate
```

Comment: if i am using delta indexes .change in my table data automatically updated in the delta indexes.

Comment: nope, if you are not using sphinx in mysql mode (as an extention to mysql) it acts as 3rd party tool. which means you have to trigger indexer. which also means it can never be "real-time", at most it can be "near real-time". One of the methods for "near real-time" is delta method which I posted as an answer.

Comment: for more information on using sphinx as mysql storage engine you can check : http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse

Comment: if any change in db directly effected delta index.it's it write.

Comment: when you trigger the indexer it would get the changes in database and apply it to index if thats what you mean, its not vice versa.